# Mensaje de espera después de ya haber descargado archivo KML

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc, model-view-controller

tardes o noche, tengo un problema con mi desarrollo en C# MVC, en el código aparentemente todo esta bien, ya que hace descarga del archivo KML con los registros que tengo, mas sin embargo al momento de finalizar la descarga, me sigue apareciendo un mensaje de carga con "porfavor espera" el cual no se quita,algunos foros sugieren que este relacionado con el cierre de la Respuesta HTTP o con el buffering en el navegador, que problemas podrían estar afectando y que soluciones deberia implementar? Gracias a todos

````
[HttpPost]
        public FileContentResult DownloadKML(DateTime Fecha)
        {


            List<Recorrido> datosCamiones = new List<Recorrido>();

            Response.Buffer = false;

            DateTime fechaSinHora = Fecha;



            datosCamiones = db.Recorridos.Where(x => x.Fecha == Fecha)
                  .OrderBy(x => x.Fecha)
                  .ThenBy(x => x.Hora).
                ToList();

            string contenidoKML = ObtenerArchivoKML(datosCamiones, fechaSinHora);


            // Convertir la cadena del archivo KML a un arreglo de bytes usando UTF-8
            byte[] archivoKMLBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(contenidoKML);

            // Deshabilitar el almacenamiento en búfer
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

            return File(archivoKMLBytes, "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml", "archivoKML.kml");



        }```
````

Comment: Y como descargas ese archivo, con una etiqueta `<a href="..">` ??????

Comment: @Yussef no, uso estas etiquetas <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>  <kml xmlns=\"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2\">

Comment: alguien sabe???

Comment: Esas etiquetas que tu muestras son del KML, lo que yo te pregunto es el método, forma, manera en que realizas la descarga (como llamas a ese controller desde el cliente)